# How to let users specify their own logical conditions (PHP / Laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am currently trying to create a web application, that saves inbound emails. I have figured out how to save the incoming emails into my database, and I have all the email information available (headers, body etc.)

I want to be able to allow my users to set *custom* conditions for each of the email inboxes they have. So image user A have three inboxes. User A decides that for Inbox 1, below rule should apply:

[image: Mockup]

Meaning that the script, in this case, should:

1. Check that the subject contains the word "Welcome!"
2. Check that the From message does not contain the word "@hotmail.com"

Now I know I can just write a "simple" `if`statement, but this will not solve my problem, as I need it to be:

1. Dynamic
2. Specific for the given inbox

I am not sure how to go around this. My first thought was to add the custom conditions for the inbox in a database (maybe in an array), and call that array on every incoming e-mail, and then maybe write custom methods for each specific rule I allow users to choose.

However, I am not sure if this is a good idea or seen as good practice?

Comment: Sounds like a good use case for a [Rules Engine](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/RulesEngine.html).

Comment: @GregBurghardt Seems like what I need. I found [Hoa/Ruler](https://github.com/hoaproject/Ruler) project, which is a ruler for PHP. My question is - should I store each users "unique" rules in a database?